# In cypress, how can we access multiple users in the fixture file?

Tags: cypress, fixtures

This is the data in fixture file called `users.json`
When we access this data from Cypress how can we access as it has multiple data in under same name.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jan Test",
    "username": "JTest",
    "email": "SJtest@testing.com",
  },    
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mark well",
    "username": "Mwell",
    "email": "mwell@makv.com",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Geet rwar",
    "username": "Grwar",
    "email": "grwar@mail.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: There're 3 elements in the array, you can access them one after the other, or choose one based on some condition you define. What data do you want? Be a more specific in your question.

Comment: @pavelsaman your edit to the question assumes there are array delimiters in `user.json` but that may not be correct.

Comment: @eric99: Yeah, I know, but the previous version was not even a valid json, so I hope this is what the OP meant. But I understand, perhaps I shouldn't've updated this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). For example

```
cy.fixture('users.json')
    .then(array => {
        const userINeed = aray.find(element => element.id === 1)
    })
```

In this code - the `array` is the data from the fixture, though it needs to be in the fixtures folder